# play hls or rtmp inside android browser

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, rtmp, http-live-streaming, m3u8

The goal is to play live streaming inside android browser, thus using the 
html5 video player.

I tried with m3u8 (which works on ios and also while tapping directly the m3u8 inside android), I tried with RTMP.

**This works on IOS, not on android**

```
<video id="my_video_1"  controls autoplay
        preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%"   data-setup="{}">
        <source src="http://mysite.com:8080/hls/video.m3u8" '/>
</video>
```

and this link works on android browser (it opens a video player )
http://mysite.com:8080/hls/video.m3u8

So: what should I do to display some live video inside android browser ?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at longtailvideo where a whole list of supported browsers and so on is available: http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/hls/
also have a look at the footnotes: Sometimes it is necessary to to click 3 times at the play button.
Also only Android 4+ supports *a little bit* of hls. But .m3u8 playlists are definitiv possible in some browsers on some devices, but it is challenging.